# How to display specific text based on attribute option id on product page view - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

i want to display specific text based on attribute option id on product page view.

Where I made a mistake?

I run this code on product page view.

```
$attribute = $_product->getMyattribute();
if ($attribute ='32') {
echo 'My text';
}
```

`var_dump($attribute);` returns 31,32,33

Then I try the following code , but again failure.

```
$attribute = $_product->getMyattribute();
    $filterName = Array();
    foreach ($attribute as $key => $value) {
    $filterName[] = $value;
    }
    if (in_array("30", $filterName)) {
        echo 'My text';
    }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**
added another solution

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("Myattribute");

if ($attribute->getSource()->getOptionText("31")) {
    echo 'My text';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$attributeIds = explode(",", $$_product->getMyattribute());

if(in_array(32, $attributeIds){
   echo 'My text';
}
```

In your first example

```
  (string)31,32,33 != (string)32
```

In your second example

```
 $attribute is a string and not an array, therefore you cannot use foreach (with out converting it to an array first)
```

eg.

```
foreach(explode(",", $$_product->getMyattribute()) as $value{
    $filterName[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, added another solution.